# Named functions in a javascript file using Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack-4

I just started using Webpack 4 in a project and am new to Webpack. Once Webpack 4 was implemented, I noticed that named functions kept erroring saying [functionName] is not defined.

I have looked quite extensively over the last few days and have tried multiple options with no success. I am hoping for someone to help me work through this in a more direct fashion way.

```
function openNav(obj) {
    ...do something
}
```

```
@foreach (object in list)
{
 ...create some HTML

}
```

```
const bundleFileName = 'bundle';
const dirName = 'wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return {
        mode: argv.mode === "production" ? "production" : "development",
        entry: [
            './src/Index.js',
            './src/css/site.css',
            './src/js/app.js'
        ],

        output: {
            filename: bundleFileName + '.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, dirName)
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery'
            }),
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: bundleFileName + '.css'
            })
        ]
    };
};
```

I expected the button in the razor file to send the object over to the named function so something can happen like it did previously before webpack

Comment: I think we need to see how you're using `openNav` in "create some HTML". I figure it's probably using `openNav` in a context where it has to be a global (for instance, and old-fashioned `onxyz`-attribute-style event handler). Since you've bundled things with Webpack, it's not a global anymore (it's in a module). Which is a good thing, but it does mean you have to hook up your events using modern techniques.

Comment: you're right. I am using it the old fashion way in the sense that in my html on the razor page, I am calling the openNav function onclick.

Answer (score 0):

You've said you're trying to use `openNav` from an `onclick` attribute. The problem there is that `openNav` has to be a **global** to be used that way, but Webpack is a *module bundler*. Functions at the top level of modules aren't globals. (Which is a good thing.)

The solution is to not use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. Instead, use modern event handling ([`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), probably with at least some event delegation).

To ease your transition from the old way to the modern way, you can expose a function globally from within a module like this (on browsers):

```
window.openNav = openNav;
```

I **strongly** recommend only doing that temporarily to make it easier to transition to modern event handling.

Answer (score 0):

thats because your webpack config isnt set to understand how to handle javascript files, add this to your rules key:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?/,
  loader: 'babel-loader'
}
```

you will also need to install babel loader that is in a version compatible with your babel core, for v7^ you need to install @babel/core @babel/loader etc, otherwise, babel-loader etc